# jQuery Array multiplication & addition

Tags: jquery, arrays, multiplication

I have two arrays:

Ex: `count["1","3","1"..........]`, `amount["10","20","30"..........]`

I need to perform multiplication & addition as:

```
var total = (1x10)+(2x20)+(1x30)...........
```

Can anyone help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code

```js
var count = [1, 3, 1];
var amount = [10, 20, 30];
var sum = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < count.length; i++) {
  sum += count[i] * amount[i];
}
console.log(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var a = ["1","3","1"], b = ["10","20","30"], sum = 0;
$.each(a, function(k,v){
 sum += (parseInt(v) * parseInt(b[k]));
})
console.log(sum); // 100
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

100